# How to rotate the text in latex table?

Tags: tables, rotating

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Rotate Text in Table across column spanning many rows](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9893/how-to-rotate-text-in-table-across-column-spanning-many-rows)

I would like to make my first column of table merger together and include a 90°-rotated text in that merged column in order to describe the entire row.

Something like:

```
┌─┬─────────┐
|A├─────────┤
| ├─────────┤
└─┴─────────┘
```

Where the text in field A is the 90°-rotated text.

Is it possible to do so?

Comment: Have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9893/3240

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Thanks for your question. Have a look at the linked one above and tell us if it answers yours. We will then close this one as a duplicate to keep the site tidy.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! And sorry for duplicate question...